# Memory leakage in cudaDecodeGL sdk sample after porting from windows to linux

Tags: c++, c, memory-leaks, cuda, valgrind

I successfully ported cudaDecodeGL from windows to linux , it works fine , but after checking memory leakage with valgrind , I found that there is alot of memory leakage in that :

I reviewed the code and for finding solution I have some question :

1) should I delete all declared pointer in all function , I mean  not deleting a pointer cause memory leakage ?

2) does porting windows program to linux make memory leakage problem , For example because of memory management mechanism in linux and windows ?!?!

3) can you give me a procedure in which you face to memory leakage in valgrind, I mean what do you do if valgrind told you you have memory leak like this ?
part of valgrind log file :

```
.
.
.
.
==10468== 754,864 (4,088 direct, 750,776 indirect) bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 136 of 137

==10468==    at 0x4A069EE: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:270)
==10468==    by 0x5B0A366: cuvidCreateVideoParser (in /usr/lib64/libnvcuvid.so.319.17)
==10468==    by 0x40929E: VideoParser::VideoParser(VideoDecoder*, FrameQueue*, CUctx_st**) (in /home/admin/testcuda/de_3/cudaDecodeGL/3_Imaging/cudaDecodeGL/Far_Decoder)
==10468==    by 0x4063F3: initCudaVideo() (in /home/admin/testcuda/de_3/cudaDecodeGL/3_Imaging/cudaDecodeGL/Far_Decoder)
==10468==    by 0x404E8B: initCudaResources(int, char**, int*) (in /home/admin/testcuda/de_3/cudaDecodeGL/3_Imaging/cudaDecodeGL/Far_Decoder)
==10468==    by 0x40561B: main (in /home/admin/testcuda/de_3/cudaDecodeGL/3_Imaging/cudaDecodeGL/Far_Decoder)
    LEAK SUMMARY:
    ==10468==    definitely lost: 7,608 bytes in 148 blocks
    ==10468==    indirectly lost: 988,728 bytes in 907 blocks
    ==10468==      possibly lost: 2,307,388 bytes in 59 blocks
    ==10468==    still reachable: 413,278 bytes in 198 blocks
    ==10468==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
```

Let me know if you need more information. If you think I should add some info to make my question clear , just let me know how to do that , I really appreciate that.

Update :

```
VideoParser::VideoParser(VideoDecoder *pVideoDecoder, FrameQueue *pFrameQueue, CUcontext *pCudaContext): hParser_(0)
{
    assert(0 != pFrameQueue);
    oParserData_.pFrameQueue   = pFrameQueue;
    assert(0 != pVideoDecoder);
    oParserData_.pVideoDecoder = pVideoDecoder;
    oParserData_.pContext      = pCudaContext;

    CUVIDPARSERPARAMS oVideoParserParameters;
    memset(&oVideoParserParameters, 0, sizeof(CUVIDPARSERPARAMS));
    oVideoParserParameters.CodecType              = pVideoDecoder->codec();
    oVideoParserParameters.ulMaxNumDecodeSurfaces = pVideoDecoder->maxDecodeSurfaces();
    oVideoParserParameters.ulMaxDisplayDelay      = 1;  // this flag is needed so the parser will push frames out to the decoder as quickly as it can
    oVideoParserParameters.pUserData              = &oParserData_;
    oVideoParserParameters.pfnSequenceCallback    = HandleVideoSequence;    // Called before decoding frames and/or whenever there is a format change
    oVideoParserParameters.pfnDecodePicture       = HandlePictureDecode;    // Called when a picture is ready to be decoded (decode order)
    oVideoParserParameters.pfnDisplayPicture      = HandlePictureDisplay;   // Called whenever a picture is ready to be displayed (display order)
    CUresult oResult = cuvidCreateVideoParser(&hParser_, &oVideoParserParameters);
    assert(CUDA_SUCCESS == oResult);
}
```

as you see cuvidCreateVideoParser is in the shared library , how can I solve this memory leakage ?

Comment: do you even know that the Windows version you ported doesn't also leak?

Comment: @talonmies , did you down-vote me ? any-way , thank you for your time to help me .

Comment: good point ,because of this I up-voted you , I have thought about testing on windows but our server is Linux , and I don't have windows to test that,So I asked this question, hope somebody had this experience with cuda decoder sdk sample, meanwhile I am looking for windows with gpu

Comment: Can you provide some sourcecode of your port? All that can be read from the valgrind output is, that in the VideoParser constructor some memory is allocated within cuvidCreateVideoParsers that is never freed.

Comment: @FarzadSalimiJazi: if you don't know whether the Windows code you ported also leaks memory, then most of your question makes no sense. And the rest is incredibly broad, which is why I voted to close this question. But what isn't clear is why it matters in the first place. The code is supposed to be a simple example. Why does it matter to you whether it has a leak or not?

Comment: @talonmies , I would really appreciate if you could let this question be open , hope somebody found what I am meaning , thanks for your time , It is very important because I want to run instances of this decoder many time and even at the same time and memory leakage is important for me but I am confused , let me know if you think additional info make my question clear , I appreciate that

Comment: @kronos, I have updated my question with videoParser constructor also up-voted you , you helped me to make my question clear , and also help me how can I deal with this report in log file , thanks for you time, I will update my question with more details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, documentation on nvcuvid does not appear on the first page on google results so a quick look at nvcuvid.h revealed:

```
CUresult CUDAAPI cuvidCreateVideoParser(CUvideoparser *pObj, CUVIDPARSERPARAMS *pParams);
CUresult CUDAAPI cuvidParseVideoData(CUvideoparser obj, CUVIDSOURCEDATAPACKET *pPacket);
CUresult CUDAAPI cuvidDestroyVideoParser(CUvideoparser obj);
```

Be sure to destroy your video parser handle via cuvidDestroyVideoParser in your deconstructor of your VideoParser class. From the small code block you provided it is not clear how long the VideoParsers lives. I suppose (due to the valgrind output) it is within a function scope and gets destroyed when the function returns. Without proper destruction of your object's cuvid resources you will encounter memory-leakage.

Comment: the VideoParser doesn't have any distractor, you mean I should define an distractor and call cuvidDestroyVideoParser in that ?

Comment: Dear @kronos ; YOU ARE AWESOME , REALLY thank you I appreciate that , you are respectful , I defined an distractor and I called cuvidDestroyVideoParser , memory leakage in parser is solved :)) , FURTHERMORE you teach me fishing so I can solve rest of memory leakage,